# Run multiple call in parallel go generate object using Futures

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have to build custom type object and there are multiple call before returning and populating object.

I have to use Java 8 Future to build  object paralally so that the code block would be more preferment.

The code looks below -

```
public CustomRequest getCustomRequest(Member member, 
    Address address,Member member){
    CustomRequest customRequest = new CustomRequest();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        populateAddress(address, customRequest);
        populatecontact(contact, customRequest);
        populateMemberDetails(member, customRequest);
    });
    return customRequest;
}
```

currently am getting "No values set in side of customRequest object" (have set some value inside populatecontact, populatecontact and populateMemberDetails to customRequest Object) as return of method call , do need to put wait on CompletableFuture or the use of Futures itself wrong.

Comment: Does `CustomRequest customRequest = customRequest CustomRequest();` even compile?

Comment: @Nicko Sorry typo corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how `customRequest ` can become null. It is instantiated in the method and this variable is returned. The populate* methods can not change the variable itself, only the content of the customRequest instance.

Comment: If you are populating data into `CustomRequest` by using `CompletableFuture.runAsync` then you have to wait

Comment: @Conffusion Its not null but its empty where as my expectation that it should be set some value inside method call  ```populateAddress(address, customRequest);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return custom request before it was populated, because your return the object while it's still being populated in a different thread. If you want the object `customRequest` to be completely populated before returning it your need to wait for the `CompletableFuture` to finish by calling the method `CompletableFuture.get()` like this:

```
public CustomRequest getCustomRequest(Member member, 
    Address address,Member member){
    CustomRequest customRequest = new CustomRequest();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        populateAddress(address, customRequest);
        populatecontact(contact, customRequest);
        populateMemberDetails(member, customRequest);
    }).get();//EDIT: added get method here to wait for the execution
    return customRequest;
}
```

But this use of `CompletableFuture` doesn't really make much sense (except that the population is done in another thread). It will still be a blocking call and you'll have to wait for the object to be populated.

You could try to use the java 8 `Future` framework like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<CustomRequest> getCustomRequest(Member member, Address address, Member member){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        CustomRequest customRequest = new CustomRequest();
        populateAddress(address, customRequest);
        populatecontact(contact, customRequest);
        populateMemberDetails(member, customRequest);
        return customRequest;
    });
}
```

This way you can create method calls like this (only an example):

```
getCustomRequest(aMember, anAddress, anotherMember).thenAccept(populatedCustomRequest -> populatedCustomRequest.doSomethingUsefull());
```

Using e.g. the method [thenAccept(Consumer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) of the class `CompletableFuture`. This would cause the method `doSomethingUsefull()` of the class `CustomRequest` to be executed on the complete populated `CustomRequest` object as soon as it is populated.